Tikz numbering time series diagram nodes using foreach
I'm trying to build a repeating graph that starts at t-1 and progresses to t+1 but I can't figure out how to print the time series correctly.
I have three identical diagrams cascaded where the left should have outputs of y(t-1), followed by y(t), and then y(t+1). The inputs should follow likewise.

I can't seem to put an if statement in the node text area to determine what the proper node label should be. I want to do something like {\ifthenelse{\i < 0}{$y_{t-1}}{\ifthenelse {\i=0}{$y_t$}{$y_{t+1}}} but this just generates errors
Secondly, is there a way to shift the drawing over so it's centered on the grid? I tried adding x=3 to either the initial \begin{tikzdrawing}[x=3] and in the \begin{scope}[x=3] but neither of those forced the initial coordinate by 3.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,automata, backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\title{tempTikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=0.1cm, font=\normalsize\sffamily, thick,%
                    arr/.style={-{Latex[scale=1.0]}, line width =1.0pt}, rounded corners = 0.1cm]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (9,5);
    \foreach \i in {-1,...,1}
    {
        \begin{scope}[xshift = \i * 3.0cm]
            \node[draw, circle] at +(2,0.5) (i\i) {$x_{t-1}$};
            \node[draw, circle] at +(2,4) (a\i) {+};
            \node[draw, rectangle] at +(2,2) (ll\i) {LSTM};
            \node[draw, rectangle] at +(3,3) (lr\i) {LSTM};
            \node at +(2.0,5.0) (l\i) {$y_{t-1}$};

            \draw[arr] (i\i) -- (ll\i);
            \draw[arr] (i\i) -| (lr\i);
            \draw[arr] (ll\i) -- (a\i);
            \draw[arr] (lr\i) |- (a\i);
            \draw[arr] (a\i) -- (l\i);
        \end{scope}
    }

    \draw[arr] (ll-1) -- (ll-0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

[edit] Made code MWE.

Welcome. // We like code like yours, and even more, when it also compiles. Please make it a habbit next time, to include the few missing lines, too. Thank you

With your code: change \node at +(2.0,5.0) (l\i) {$y_{t\i}$}; and \draw[help lines] (-3,0) grid (6,5);

Here is one way to do it:

For the indices you can define and use pairs in the foreach loop, like so:
\foreach \i/\t in {0/t-1, 1/t, 2/t+1}               % <<<
...
        \node at +(2.0,5.0) (l\i) {$y_{\t}$};               % <<<

For the shift there are several possibilities. One is to adjust your shift-coordinates a little.
I prefer creating and compiling drawings separately, which gives you more freedom and less unwanted interaction in your main document. How to combine, see e.g. here.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    rounded corners=0.1cm, 
    font=\normalsize\sffamily, 
    thick,%
    arr/.style={-{Latex[scale=1.0]}, 
    line width =1.0pt}, 
%    rounded corners = 0.1cm            % duplicate
    ]
\draw[help lines,draw=gray!30] (0,0) grid (9,5);    % <<<
\foreach \i/\t in {0/t-1, 1/t, 2/t+1}               % <<<
{
    \begin{scope}[xshift = \i * 3.0cm - 1cm]        % <<<
        \node[draw, circle,minimum size=1cm]        % <<<
                            at +(2,0.5) (i\i) {$x_{\t}$};   % <<<
        \node[draw, circle] at +(2,4) (a\i) {+};
        \node[draw, rectangle] at +(2,2) (ll\i) {LSTM};
        \node[draw, rectangle] at +(3,3) (lr\i) {LSTM};
        \node at +(2.0,5.0) (l\i) {$y_{\t}$};               % <<<

        \draw[arr] (i\i) -- (ll\i);
        \draw[arr] (i\i) -| (lr\i);
        \draw[arr] (ll\i) -- (a\i);
        \draw[arr] (lr\i) |- (a\i);
        \draw[arr] (a\i) -- (l\i);
    \end{scope}
}

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


P.S., just for my understanding: y(t) = 2 * LSTM(x(t)) ?

That's slick. I forget that I can 'index' by random things.

to your P.S. the answer is sorta. The diagram isn't complete. For a Bi-LSTM there's an arrow going left - right through the bottom LSTMs showing the input sequence begin stepped in the forward direction and another arrow right - left through the upper LSTMs signifying the input sequence stepping backwards.
